# is there a pandas function to strip off the invisible string(" ") in a pandas column

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, jupyter-notebook

how to convert '5000' to int64.

Comment: Can you add more details about your data and what you are trying to accomplish? What are the other values of the column you are trying to convert?

Comment: I am trying to convert an object to int.  The values are int but recognized as object

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Option 1:

```
import pandas as pd

data={'Name':['Daniel','Tobi','Juwon','Ade'],'Age':['17','21','21','24']}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df.Age = df.Age.str.strip().astype(int)
print(df.dtypes)
print('______________')
print(df)
```

This returns:

```
Name    object
Age      int64
dtype: object
______________
     Name  Age
0  Daniel   17
1    Tobi   21
2   Juwon   21
3     Ade   24
```

Option 2:

```
import pandas as pd

data={'Name':['Daniel','Tobi','Juwon','Ade', 'Ola'],'Age':['17','21','21',' 24  ', '  nene33']}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

def to_integer(x):
    try:
        return int(x)
    except Exception as e:
        return 0

df.Age = df.Age.apply(lambda x: to_integer(x))

print(df.dtypes)
print('______________')
print(df)
```

This returns:

```
Name    object
Age      int64
dtype: object
______________
     Name  Age
0  Daniel   17
1    Tobi   21
2   Juwon   21
3     Ade   24
4     Ola    0
```

Comment: ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '55,000'

Comment: post your data (dataframe as dict, copy/pastable) and I will amend my answer

Comment: import pandas as pd

data={'Name':['Daniel','Tobi','Juwon','Ade'],'Age':['17','21','21','24']}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

df

Comment: trying to convert the age to int

Comment: Updated response - it should now do what you need

Comment: Yeah, this does work here. But still not working for the main dataset

Comment: So then post the main dataset

Comment: I have added another option - check my updated response and let me know if it helped.